# Can't installing PIL with pip in a virtualenv in Windows Vista

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library, virtualenv, pip

I created a new virtualenv named `renamover` and then tried to install `pil` with `pip` but I believe installation got stuck because the `Build` directory that is created during `pip` installations never got deleted. The following shows the `build\pil` directory located in my `renamover` virtualenv:

```
(renamover) C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons\renamover>dir build\pil
 Volume in drive C is SQ004814V03
 Volume Serial Number is A045-86B5

 Directory of C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons\renamover\build\pil

04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          .
04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          build
04/25/2012  01:58 PM               239 BUILDME
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            63,751 CHANGES
04/25/2012  01:58 PM             8,940 CONTENTS
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            16,520 decode.c
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            20,783 display.c
04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          Docs
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            35,988 doctest.py
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            13,230 encode.c
04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          Images
04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          libImaging
04/25/2012  01:58 PM             6,688 MANIFEST
04/25/2012  01:58 PM             8,953 map.c
04/25/2012  01:58 PM             3,869 outline.c
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            14,282 path.c
04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          PIL
04/25/2012  01:58 PM                 4 PIL.pth
04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          pip-egg-info
04/25/2012  01:58 PM               780 PKG-INFO
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            10,642 README
04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          Sane
04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          Scripts
04/25/2012  01:58 PM             5,632 selftest.py
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            17,323 setup.py
04/25/2012  01:58 PM    <DIR>          Tk
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            84,558 _imaging.c
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            16,792 _imagingcms.c
04/25/2012  01:58 PM            13,843 _imagingft.c
04/25/2012  01:58 PM             6,720 _imagingmath.c
04/25/2012  01:58 PM             1,456 _imagingtk.c
              21 File(s)        350,993 bytes
              11 Dir(s)   3,643,211,776 bytes free
```

And here are the errors/warnings that showed up in the prompt during installation:

```
C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons>virtualenv --distribute renamover

New python executable in renamover\Scripts\python.exe
Installing distribute.................................................
......................................................................
......................................................................
..done.
Installing pip.................done.

C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons>cd renamover

C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons\renamover>pip install pil
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons\renamover>Scripts\activate

(renamover) C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons\renamover>pip
install pil
Downloading/unpacking pil
  Downloading PIL-1.1.7.tar.gz (506Kb): 506Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pil
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated p
ackage names in setup.py

Installing collected packages: pil
  Running setup.py install for pil
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated p
ackage names in setup.py
    building '_imaging' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\
pythons\renamover\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import setuptools;__file__='
C:\\Users\\s3z\\Desktop\\My Dropbox\\pythons\\renamover\\build\\pi
l\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
 __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --rec
ord c:\users\s3z\appdata\local\temp\pip-hyfdad-record\install-reco
rd.txt --install-headers "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons\
renamover\include\site\python2.7":
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated p
ackage names in setup.py

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ArgImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageFileIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageGL.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\OleFileIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

copying PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

running build_ext

building '_imaging' extension

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons\renamover\Scripts
\python.exe" -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Users\\s3z\\Deskt
op\\My Dropbox\\pythons\\renamover\\build\\pil\\setup.py';exec(compile
(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" inst
all --single-version-externally-managed --record c:\users\s3z\appd
ata\local\temp\pip-hyfdad-record\install-record.txt --install-headers
"C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons\renamover\include\site\py
thon2.7" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropb
ox\pythons\renamover\build\pil
Storing complete log in C:\Users\s3z\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

Additionally, when I try to `import pil` in the `renamover` virtualenv Python interpreter I get an `ImportError` like so:

```
(renamover) C:\Users\s3z\Desktop\My Dropbox\pythons\renamover>python

Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD6
4)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pil
```

So how do I properly install `pil` using `pip` in a virtualenv on Windows Vista?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) instead as PIL-compatible fork.

I have problems with PIL installing even on Linux :)